# upload pic error php

Tags: php, sql

```
if(isset($_FILES['school_logo']['name']) && $_FILES['school_logo']['name'] != "") {

    if( ($_FILES['school_logo']["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || 
        ($_FILES['school_logo']["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
        ($_FILES['school_logo']["type"] == "image/gif") || 
        ($_FILES['school_logo']["type"] == "image/png")) {

        $db_coulm_val            = "";
        $directory               = "../uploads/schools_logos/";
        $logo_name               = $_FILES['school_logo']['name'];
        $twmporayr_logo_name     = $_FILES['school_logo']['tmp_name'];
        $complete_directory_name = $directory.time().$_FILES['school_logo']['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($twmporayr_logo_name, $complete_directory_name)) {
            $db_coulm_val = " s_logo = '".$logo_name."', "; 
        } else {
            echo "ERROR Uploading Logo....";
        }
    }

    else

    {
        echo "<h2 style='color:red; text-align:center;'>Sorry Only Jpg, Png and Gif Formats are Allowed For Images.</h2>";
        die();
    }
}
```

This is part of a form for a user to upload a picture.  I can't get the picture to upload.  The SQL does retain the file name. It correctly gives me an error when allowing only the specified file extensions.  If there was an error it doesn't echo ERROR Uploading Logo....  it seems like everything works except for the actual part of uploading the picture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about getting the actual error?

Comment: What is: $directory.time() .. which sets the directory

Comment: You could replace your whole first if statement with `if(!empty($_FILES['school_logo']['name']))`

Comment: GrumpyCrouton should have posted the answer and explained since it worked for you. This way you have answered your own question without explanation. And now, since your answer is correct I guess you will be accepting your own answer? :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a working example of a proper image upload file. At first I didn't understand you example properly. I have now edited to add the proper variables.

Here is the code:

```
// Check if file was uploaded without errors
if(isset($_FILES["school_logo"]) && $_FILES["school_logo"]["error"] == 0) {
    // allowed image types
    $allowed = array(
        "jpg" => "image/jpg",
        "pjpg" => "image/pjpeg",
        "jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
        "gif" => "image/gif",
        "png" => "image/png"
    );
    // some (incoming) file properties
    $filename = $_FILES["school_logo"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["school_logo"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["school_logo"]["size"];

    // Verify file extension (here we are comparing the file extension to the keys of $allowed array)
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {
        echo "Error: Please select a valid file format.<br/>";
    }

    // Verify file size - 5MB maximum (5MB is example, you can set anything)
    $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    if($filesize > $maxsize) {
        echo "Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.<br/>";

    }

    // Verify MYME type of the file (here we are comparing the file MYME type to the $allowed array values)
    if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)) {
        $db_coulm_val = "";
        $directory = "../uploads/schools_logos/";
        $logo_name = $_FILES['school_logo']['name'];
        $twmporayr_logo_name = $_FILES['school_logo']['tmp_name'];
        $complete_directory_name = $directory.time().$_FILES['school_logo']['name'];
        // Check whether file exists before uploading it
        if(file_exists("../uploads/schools_logos/" . $_FILES["school_logo"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["school_logo"]["name"] . " already exists.<br/>";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($twmporayr_logo_name, $complete_directory_name);

            $db_coulm_val = " s_logo = '" . $logo_name . "', ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["school_logo"]["error"] . "<br/>";
}
```